# How does the body respond to having excess levels of neuronal, not synaptic, serotonin?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuro-transmitters, serotonin

If a person consumes large amounts of 5-HTP or SAM-e resulting in elevated serotonin levels in their synaptic vesicles, how is this excess offloaded? What is the average rate of clearance?

All the literature I can find deals with serotonin syndrome which concerns synaptic serotonin, and is caused by substances that prevent transport of the serotonin from the synapse like antidepressants and lithium.

What I want to know is:

- Do the neurons release more serotonin into the synapse in response to surplus serotonin (i.e. if you have it, spend it)?
- What is the mechanism that causes neurotransmitters to be released into the synapse called? I know the thing that removes it is a transporter.

Comment: Serotonin syndrome is not specifically about synaptic serotonin, (induced by reuptake inhibitors).  A multitude of drugs, acting through different mechanisms, can lead to an accumulation of serotonin in the body.